# How do i change svg attributes with js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Today I got some problems changing the attributes of a svg with js using the `onclick` method;

here is what i want to do:

[image: what i want to do]

here is what I did:

[image: what i did]

(**there is the arrow, but the grey covers it**)

---

Here is my code:

```js
function social() {
  document.getElementById("svg1").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  document.getElementById("arrow").setAttribute("fill", "#ff00ff")
}
```

```html
<div id="svg1">
  <svg id="arrow" onclick="social()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13">
    <path fill="#6E8098"
    d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `document.getElementById("arrow")` you are searching the `<svg>` element.
Then you are changing its `fill` attribute, but the `fill` attribute of the  `<path />` element overwrites it. So you have to either move `id="arrow"` from the `<svg>` to the `path` move the `fill` from the `<path />` to the `<svg>`

```js
function social() {
  document.getElementById("svg1").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  document.getElementById("arrow").setAttribute("fill", "#ff00ff")
}
```

```html
<div id="svg1">
  <svg onclick="social()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13">
    <path id="arrow" fill="#6E8098"
    d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

or

```js
function social() {
  document.getElementById("svg1").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  document.getElementById("arrow").setAttribute("fill", "#ff00ff")
}
```

```html
<div id="svg1">
  <svg id="arrow" onclick="social()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13" fill="#6E8098">
    <path 
    d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a CSS class and then using `classlist.toggle` to move it onclick:

```js
function social() {
  document.getElementById("arrow").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.active > path {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg1">
  <svg id="arrow" onclick="social()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13">
    <path id='path' fill="#6E8098"
    d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```